# Как сделать плавное вращение градиента в svg?

Tags: svg, svg-animation

Есть рамка с линейным градиентом.
Хочется, чтобы градиент вращался, т.е чтобы менялось свойство `gradientTransform="rotate(40)"`

В документации сказано что свойство gradientTransform "Animatable"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientTransform

Скажите пожалуйста - как его анимировать?

Я бы хотел чтобы градиент вращался от 0 до 360 градусов.

```html
 <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  viewBox="0 0 240 120"  
>
     <defs>
      <linearGradient id="linearGradient"  gradientTransform="rotate(40)"  >
       <stop style="stop-color:violet; stop-opacity: .7;" offset="0%"/>
       <stop style="stop-color:blue; stop-opacity: .4;" offset="40%"/>
       <stop style="stop-color:orange" offset="90%"/>
      </linearGradient>
     </defs>

     <g >
       <rect x="5" y="5" width="230" height="110" ry="10" 
             style="fill:none;stroke-width:5;stroke:url(#linearGradient);" /> 

          <animateTransform 
          attributeName="gradientTransform" 
          type="rotate" 
          from="0"
          to="45"
          repeatCount="indefinite" 
          dur="25s" 
        />
      
     </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы применяете анимацию вращения градиента к прямоугольнику, а нужно размещать команду анимации градиента внутри определения градиента.

Немного изменил для наглядности время и углы поворота.  Всегда можете настроить эти параметры под себя.

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  viewBox="0 0 240 120"  
>
     <defs>
      <linearGradient id="linearGradient"  gradientTransform="rotate(0)"  >
       <stop style="stop-color:violet; stop-opacity: .7;" offset="0%"/>
       <stop style="stop-color:blue; stop-opacity: .4;" offset="40%"/>
       <stop style="stop-color:orange" offset="90%"/>
          <animateTransform 
          attributeName="gradientTransform" 
          type="rotate" 
          values="0;90;90;0;0"
          repeatCount="indefinite" 
          dur="4s" 
        />
   </linearGradient>
     </defs>

     <g >
       <rect x="5" y="5" width="230" height="110" ry="10" 
             style="fill:none;stroke-width:5;stroke:url(#linearGradient);" /> 
     </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

Так у меня получилось - без animateTransform

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 240 120">
     <defs>
        <linearGradient id="g1" x1="0%" y1="50%" >
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" >
                <animate id="a1" attributeName="stop-color" values="red; blue" begin="0; a2.end" dur="1s" />
                <animate id="a2" attributeName="stop-color" values="blue; red" begin="a1.end" dur="1s" />
            </stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue" >
                <animate id="a3" attributeName="stop-color" values="blue; red" begin="0; a4.end" dur="1s" />
                <animate id="a4" attributeName="stop-color" values="red; blue" begin="a3.end" dur="1s" />
            </stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
<rect x="5" y="5" width="230" height="110" ry="10" style="fill:none;stroke-width:5;stroke:url(#g1);" /> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо! 
Отличный пример. Но мне почему то не давался animateTransform

Answer (score 3):

В первом ответе для получения эффекта вращения градиента использовалась команда анимации вращения градиента

```
 <animateTransform 
          attributeName="gradientTransform" 
          type="rotate" 
          values="0;90;90;0;0"
          repeatCount="indefinite" 
          dur="4s" 
        />
```

Здесь будет использована команда анимации `stop-color` линейного градиента

```
<stop style="stop-color:violet" offset="0">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="0.8s" values="violet;blue;violet" begin="rec.click" repeatCount="2" />
   </stop>
```

Ниже полный код:

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 237 113" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient" x1="-36" x2="200" y1="148" y2="148" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop style="stop-color:violet" offset="0">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="0.8s" values="violet;blue;violet" begin="rec.click" repeatCount="3" />
   </stop>
   <stop style="stop-color:blue" offset="0.8">
    <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="1.0s" values="blue;orange;blue" begin="rec.click" repeatCount="3" />
   </stop>
   <stop style="stop-color:orange" offset="1">
    <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="1.5s" values="orange;violet;orange" begin="rec.click" repeatCount="3" />
   </stop>
  
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g id="rec" transform="translate(36 -91)">
  <rect  x="-35" y="93" width="234" height="110" ry="18" style="fill:transparent;stroke-width:2;stroke:url(#linearGradient)"/>
   <text x="0" y="158" font-size="48" fill="url(#linearGradient)" >Click me</text>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Саша ..я даже не знал что в value можно писать color ...спасибо за этот пример